# How can I reset a select tag using Vue 3.js?

Tags: javascript, laravel, asynchronous, vuejs3, inertiajs

I have a component called 'SelectInput' and a button that is associated with a method named 'limpiarCampos'

```
<!-- ==========SELECT COMPONENT============= -->
<select-input id="ciudades" label="Ciudad" class="text-sm pb-1 lg:pr-3 w-full lg:w-1/2"
                            ref="selectInputComponentCiudad" v-model="form.search_ciudad">
    <option :value="null" :selected="form.search = null" />
    <option v-for="ciudad in ciudades" :key="ciudad.id" :value="ciudad.id" class="capitalize">
                                {{ ciudad.nombre_ciudad }}
     </option>
</select-input>
<!-- ==========RESET BUTTON============= -->
 <div class="py-3 text-right">
   <button class="btn-indigo" type="button" @click="limpiarCampos()">
        Limpiar
   </button>
</div>
```

My goal is that when the user presses the button, the value of the variable 'form.search_ciudad' (a reactive variable) is set to 'null,' and the select tag is reset. So i tried this:

```
const limpiarCampos = async () => {
    form.search_ciudad = null
      }
```

But only the variable 'form.search_ciudad' is set to null; the select tag still displays the previously selected option. I attempted to resolve the issue by also setting the selected index to 0, but now I am facing a synchronization problem. Currently, I have this

```
const limpiarCampos = async () =
 form.search_ciudad = null
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
 selectInputComponentCiudad.value.$refs.selecting.selectedIndex = 0
       }
```

Could someone please assist me in resolving this issue? Thank you very much to everyone.

Comment: `<option :value="null" :selected="form.search = null" />` - this is wrong, you're not supposed to do an assignment in the attribute, what exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: @Shaya Ulman Oh, yes, it was incorrect. I was just trying anything at that point. I want to reset the select and set 'form.search_ciudad' to null.